# Matching a number and everything afterwards up until another number in Regex?

Tags: regex

I've spent way too many minutes on this now, so I thought I'd try my luck here instead.

I need a regex pattern that matches a whole number and *everything* afterwards up until another whole number appears. So in the following string:

```
50 !#!#€test30testtest 20!!!!`
```

it should match:

- `50 !#!#€test`
- `30testtest`
- `20!!!!`

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What expressions have you tried? What was the result?

Comment: None that worked :) I'm not that good at this regex stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\d+\D+
```

does exactly that.

`\d+` matches one or more digits, and `\D+` matches one or more non-digits.

If you put each part in parentheses, you can then access the matches separately: `(\d+)(\D+)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  `([0-9]*[\D]*)`

I tried it in rubular and here is the result for your test string:

> `http://rubular.com/r/qQiAbMlbQf`

Comment: This is the only pattern that actually matches the captures requested (once the answer has been edited to show code - it is currently hiding the asterix's). +1 for using a tool like rubular

Answer (score 1):

The following matches numbers and option all non-numbers after the number.

```
/[\d]+[^\d]*/
```

Comment: The difference to Tim's solution is that a single number without following non-numbers will also match. It's up to you wich suits your needs better.